# Save image from URL with serializer

Tags: python, django, http, request, django-rest-framework

I am creating an API that saves images in a django model. Through the API is sent a URL and django is responsible for downloading the image and saving it in the model.

This is my model:

```
class Picture(Media):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=picture_path, blank=True, null=True)
    entity = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ENTITIES,
                          default=ENTITY_CLASIFICADO)
```

This is my serializer:

```
class PictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ("pk", "image", "entity",)
```

From the URL I generate a PIL object. How do I specify the serializer that stores the object? My views.py

```
class PictureViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        r = requests.get(request.data["url"])
        img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete = True)
        img_temp.write(r.content)
```

Now, I'm saving the empty image field.

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
```

I would like to add the PIL object to request.data and it looks like this:

```
<QueryDict: {'url': ['https://s3.amazonaws.com/cat/encabezado.jpg'], 'image': ['MY PIL IMAGE'], 'entity': ['clasificado'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['JRMLIXkxqg6sF5YP19NLTvgFOmVWH9ARSmM']}>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that directly in serialiser
So basically it is real life working example, note that we need to set image as relative path when setting it in `attrs`.
Also you need to check status of response, but this i'll leave up to you )

```
import os, uuid, requests
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from .models import Audio

class AudioCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Audio
        fields = ['image']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        url = "http://youurlgoeshere.com/sddsjdsjdsjds.png"
        data = requests.get(url)
        response = requests.get(image_url)
        random_name = uuid.uuid4().hex + ".png"
        folder_name = "custom_images"
        absolute_file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, folder_name, random_name)
        relative_path = os.path.join(folder_name, random_name)
        with open(absolute_file_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        attrs['image'] = relative_path
        return attrs
```

Also, i'll leave here how to define views

```
class AudioListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    queryset = Audio.objects.select_related("artist")

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == "GET":
            return AudioListSerializer
        if self.request.method == "POST":
            return AudioCreateSerializer
```